# How to copy one formGroup to the other in Angular?

Tags: angular, formgroups

If I want to copy a `formgroup` to other, what is the best option?

For example, if message is my `formgroup` which has widgets array that needs to be copied to the pageForm `fromgroup` which has similar structure as of message.

I tried:

`(<FormArray>this.pageForm.get('widgets')).push(<FormArray>this.message.get('widgets'))`

Comment: Docs show that ``FormGroup`` has methods like ``addControl`` and ``registerControl`` which could be a more appropriate way to do that - did you check them?

Comment: Do you want to copy only controls? If you want to copy controls you can try this:
newFormGroup = new FormGroup(message.controls)

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to copy the data, you can use `patchValue`:

```
this.form.targetGroup.patchValue(this.form.sourceGroup.value);
```

Here is the angular doc for [FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) and [patchValue](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#patchValue).